# How to obtain the variable except the options in bash scripts?

Tags: linux, shell

I made a script and the usage should be:

```
bash test.sh -r chr1:1000-2000 -n 123 test_1.fq test_2.fq
```

I want to get the input `test_1.fq test_2.fq` at the end of input.

But when I used `$*` in the script, `input=$*`, I just got the whole input `-r chr1:1000-2000 -n 123 test_1.fq test_2.fq`.

Other options (-r -n) were obtained normally using `getopts`.

How could I keep only the last two words?

Comment: Show your `getopts` code? You probably want something like `${@:OPTIND}`.

Comment: After you executed getopts, you probably forgot to `shift $((OPTIND - 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Just [`shift`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/shift) all the parameters until you just have two:

```
while (( $# > 2 )); do
   shift
done

echo "$@"
```

From the linked page:

> The `shift` builtin command is used to "shift" the positional
>   parameters by the given number n or by 1, if no number is given.

Note also that the way to use the given parameters is with `$@`, not `$*`.

Answer (score 1):

Use shift:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

It removes the left most parameters.   If you know the number you need to remove then this is the solution.  If you know how many you need after shifting then the other answer will work :)

```
$ ./a.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+ shift 4
+ echo 5 6 7
5 6 7
```

Comment: The TLDP bash guides (at least the ABS) are generally not so good. That said that page is actually fairly decent.